# R: using multinom() for a very large data set

Tags: r, memory, bigdata, multinomial

I am trying to run a multinomial logistic regression on my dataset using the multinom package. My data set has 25029 rows and 5735 columns, and basically doing:

```
test <- multinom(5735th_var ~ ., data = training.set...etc)
```

I have gotten into several errors which have made me adjust two options:

```
maxit = 1000, MaxNWts = 143541315
```

in my multinom function.

However, now I am facing more warnings (after running it for 30+minutes):

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 592 Kb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
  Reached total allocation of 30719Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
  Reached total allocation of 30719Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
  Reached total allocation of 30719Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
  Reached total allocation of 30719Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I'm not an expert when it comes to computer memory, ram and all that stuff, and I looked into some big data manipulation on R, but I'm still not really getting what I could do to successfully run this code.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you serious? You are using all variables ( 5735)?

Comment: Yes it's really unfortunate but I am dealing with some large medical data.

Comment: You might want to post this on Cross Validated instead, asking about alternatives to multinomial logistic regression when you want/need to explore such a large model space. I don't see how you're going to escape this memory limit problem with so many covariates and such a large sample.

Comment: Also nearly impossible to imagine the result of this regression with 5735 variables being at all useful.

Comment: You need to do some thinking before throwing data at algorithms.

Comment: i tried my best to reduce the number of variables but it's still in the 3000's. The reason I have so many independent variables is the data I have is patient data with thousands of diagnoses and procedures possible.

Comment: It's been a while since this was asked, however this is a common problem. I think this calls for some feature engineering to reduce the dimension of the input feature space. I guess one can try domain-specific knowledge to associate some diagnostic test results into meaningful subcategories or, as a mathematical alternative, use a technique like principal component analysis to obtain statistically meaningful variables but likely with little medical meaning.